# How to dynamically change tab title when it is not selected?

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, title

I want to display dynamic information (score) in the window tab of a javascript games running in a browser (chrome) : my goal is to run several instances of the game in different tabs, running in parallel, and to be able to see the current scores in the tab titles. I tried :

document.title = score

... but it works only in the selected tab, the other one are not refreshed until selected (although the games are running well in background).

==> is there a way to force the update of the tab titles... even if not selected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found couple of same questions on the http://stackoverflow.com but they did not work for me.

You can find your solution here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2010/10/19/Using-JavaScript-to-update-the-browser-window-title-when-the-user-is-away

So, basically that kind of code will work:

```
var focused = true;
var baseTitle = "";
var chatsMissed = 0;

//I'm the fake function that represents some process. We randomly determine if a new chat happened
function fakeStuff() {
if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
if(!focused) {
chatsMissed++;
window.document.title = baseTitle + " ("+chatsMissed+")";
}
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {

//store the base title
baseTitle = window.document.title;

//When the window is focused...
$(window).focus(function() {
focused = true;
//  window.document.title = baseTitle;
//chrome bug: http://heyman.info/2010/oct/7/google-chrome-bug-when-setting-document-title/
setTimeout(function() {
document.title = baseTitle;
}, 100);

chatsMissed = 0;
});

//When the window is blurred...
$(window).blur(function() {
focused = false;
});

//setup a process
window.setInterval('fakeStuff()',2000);
})
```

Unfortunately JSfiddle do not support title changing. But I tested, and it works.

Comment: After some trouble, it finally works, thanks for your help. The short answer is to add : function timer() { window.document.title = score; } window.setInterval(timer,2000);